# Damaged carbon fibre wheels

Tags: wheels, carbon

Can anybody tell me if you can repair a Wolber Carima carbon fibre wheel that has a chip on the rim?

Comment: It might, or might not, depend on the exact nature of the chip. Can you upload some photos?

Comment: You as a home repairer probably can't repair carbon fibre properly.  Check with Wobler about repairs that will be up to standard and will not void any warranty.

Comment: @Criggie - I suspect the warranty is already voided.

Comment: If the chip is not structurally significant, and just needs filling in then yes probably. The trick of course is knowing if it's structurally significant. The only way to find out is going to a professional CFC repair service.

Comment: @ArgentiApparatus There does come a point where it's easy to tell, though:  if you see exposed or broken/cut carbon fibers, the wheel is done.

Comment: You could add a photo to this question - that may help us give a more definite answer.  Otherwise the question's answers could be opinion or err on the side of caution.

Answer (score 4):

Wheels are considered being too critical for riding safety to be repaired in case of carbon failure. A professional carbon-repair shop is unlikely to accept carbon wheels, cranks, handlebars, seatposts for repair.

A couple of quotes found on the web to back up my statement.

- From https://calfeedesign.com/carbon-repair-faq/:

> What do you not repair?
>
> Frequently rejected repairs include: aluminum-to-carbon bonding, carbon handlebars, forks, seat posts/integrated seat posts, stems, damage to **carbon wheels**, and metal frames.

- From http://ruckuscomp.com/getarepair : only frame parts can be specified, not wheels.
- From https://www.donsbikeshop.com/about/carbon-fiber-frame-repair-pg289.htm

> We don't repair wheels (even though the replacement cost is higher than the repair) because the forces exerted on the rim and the need to get the wheel balanced perfectly preclude a carbon fiber repair.

- From http://joescarbonrepair.com/ says:

> What do you not repair?
>
> Frequently rejected repair requests are ones that involve aluminum-to-carbon bonding, carbon handlebars, forks, and damage involving the braking surface of **carbon wheels**.

- However, https://www.applemanbicycles.com/repair/ says:

> Carbon Repair Capabilities
>   I can fix a wide variety of carbon fiber damage to your frame. The most common repairs are: ...
>
> Disc Wheels (aero)